# How to include text next to php variable in heredoc text

Tags: php, heredoc, nowdoc

My actual use case involves filling in javascript variable names with partial id's from php, but to illustrate the issue here's a simple example with html:

```
$var="ello worl";

echo <<<HTML

H$var d

HTML;
```

I want the output to be "Hello world" however of course there is a space after the $var variable name so the output is "Hello worl d". If I remove the space, then it changes the variable name.

How do I place text next to the right side of the variable?

I've tried quotes and escaping etc. but to no avail.

Comment: I always use brackets `{$var}`. This also makes it possible to use more advanced variables, such as object members `{$myobj->property}` or array references `{$myarr[123]}`

Comment: Please read the official docs where this question gets resolved: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose the variable in curly braces (`{` and `}`) to ensure the PHP interpeter knows which characters are part of the variable name and which are static text.

```
$var="ello worl";

echo <<<HTML

H{$var}d

HTML;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/TYgEF

Documentation reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: this continues to run HEREDOC after the html;  meanining php after is not parased

Comment: @DOMDocumentVideoSource no it doesn't- demo: https://3v4l.org/BRGig